# django reset-password views, NoReverseMatch error and also problems with templates

Tags: python, django

I need to include password reset function to my app, but always I have *NoReverseMatch* error. In addition, I can't view my own templates for password reset process. I created templates in registration folder in the same directory with other templates for my app: *myapp/templates/registration*

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    .....
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, 
        name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, 
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-
        9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, 
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

I have no custom views for password reset. Should I create views for it? Thanks in advance. Django version 1.11

Answer (score 0):

As for the folder structure, you should follow django docs recommendation, wich states that you should create a subfolder in templates with the name of the app:

> Template namespacing
>
> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly
> in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory),
> but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first
> template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with
> the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to
> distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the
> right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them.
> That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for
> the application itself.

```
 myapp/templates/myapp/registration #if this is a folder you call it in the views as 'myapp/registration/page.html'
```